# Solr export query into CSV File

Tags: java, solr

Hie, I m using java and solr as search engine to export the data into csv format.The sequence of step which i m following 
--Based on the input parameter i m making a query Let say Q.
--After that i m creating a java Process p to execute that query.
--The Response which i got from solr server i need to push it into a csv file at any location.

```
enter code here
    String Q = "http://pcam-stg-app-03:9999/solr/brm-royalty/select?
    q=VENDOR_NAME:\"SOME_NAME\"&f1=vendor_name,vendor_id&wt=csv";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Q);
    p.getInputStream();
```

This stream i need to write in csv file any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Beware of just paging through the query to get all results...that is an antipattern. If the query returned many docs, and you want all of them, you need to use [cursorMark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results).

Comment: I got your point But main question is to create a csv out of the inputStream.
I can define a row limit in query itself. @Persimmonium

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the CSV response writer and SOLRJ to page through all of the results sending it to something like apache commons fileutils:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(output.csv), outputLine ("line.separator"), true);
```

Would be quiet quick to knock up in Java.

Comment: Solrj do not support csv formatted response. Hence i need a httpClient here to make request.and than i need to write the complete input stream to csv @Sumit Deshpande